# Not getting refund of my money from JobsInDubai.com

Tags: contract-law, fraud, payment

I have registered an account with JobsInDubai.com and paid 92$ to them on 2015, which they assured that is a refundable amount. And they said I can request for the refund after 6 months if I don't like their service. After the 6 months, I have send email requesting for refund. But they simply asked me to send the mail to another department, then asked to wait for their call, and some blah blah stuff.

Since I got busy, I didn't bothered to ping them again and again. And this January 2017, I have mailed them again. A couple of months ago, I have mailed them again asking why they delayed it and requested to refund it at the earliest. Then they said that the company is under new management(June 2016 onwards) and they need to verify whether am eligible for the refund. They said the refund will be initiated only for those payments made before June 10th 2016. I have send them proof stating that I paid on March 2015. But till now I have not received the refund!

Whenever I call the customercare, they apologize for the inconvenience and asked me to wait as they have notified the refund department. But no response. So what am I supposed to do now? Am from India. So do I have to file a consumer complaint in the Indian Consumer Court? The JobsInDubai.com has its headoffice at Canada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a breach of contract, and not a fraud, unless you can prove that they had no intent of refunding your money when they told you it was refundable, which would cost thousands of dollars to do, even if you could manage to prove it.

As a practical matter, however, the cost of obtaining relief in time and money may exceed the $92 you could recover. Even if you went to court and got a default judgment against them for $92 plus court costs plus interest, it would cost an immense amount of time and money to identify assets from which you could collect and then use writs of execution and writs of garnishment to collect it. If the amount of money were $92,000 it would be worth it, but it would probably not be worth it even to get $9,200 returned and there is no way that it is cost effective to pursue this for $92, even if that is a lot of money for you.

Your time is better spent giving them bad social media reviews and then moving on.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be that, they do not wish to refund the money. I would say this was the worst service from a company!